# Adding a new value in property and adding to list of an object overwrites the property of the already added object C#

Tags: c#, list

```
internal List<Employee> CreateEmployees(OrderBean[] orders, List<AbacTradeRecord> tradeRecord, Employee originalOrder, TradingService trading)
{
    List<long> ordersSuccessful;
    List<long> ordersFailed;
    List<AbacOrder> processedOrders = new List<AbacOrder>();
    try
    {
        if (!OrderValidation.CheckIfSecurityIsActive(tradeRecord.First().Environment, orders))
            return null;
        if (!OrderValidation.CheckIfAllocationsWillOversell(trading, orders))
            return null;
        OrderSvcReturn[] orderServiceReturns = trading.createOrder(orders, null);

        EmployeeCommon.HasErrorsOrWarningsParallel(orderServiceReturns, out ordersSuccessful, out ordersFailed);
        if (ordersFailed.Count()>=1)
            return null;
        //Trace.WriteLine("Order been created - New OrderId: " + orderServiceReturns[0].id + " Original Order_id: " + tradeRecord.order_id);
        foreach(var orderSuccessful in ordersSuccessful)
        {
            AbacOrder processedOrdersHold = new AbacOrder();
            OrderBean order = new OrderBean();
            order = EmployeeCommon.GetOrder(trading, orderSuccessful);
            originalOrder.EmailMessages = Logger.EmailAndTraceMessage(originalOrder.EmailMessages, "New Employee Successfully Created: "
                + order.orderId, DateTime.UtcNow + " New Order Successfully Created: " + order.orderId + " Order created in environment: "
                + originalOrder.SuccessFile);
            originalOrder.OrderBean = order;
            processedOrdersHold = originalOrder;
            processedOrders.Add(processedOrdersHold);
        }

        return processedOrders;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

In the above code ordersSuccessful has a list of 2 values. When I query GetOrder I get two different OrderBean which I am assigning to originalOrder (passed as a parameter and also has other property that I need). I assign it to variable processedOrdersHold (which I new everytime in the foreach loop). After that I add to processOrders list.
But Everytime the originalOrder.OrderBean gets overwritten. Please can someone tell why?
Thanks.

Comment: You're overwriting originalOrder.OrderBean here: `originalOrder.OrderBean = order;`

Comment: yes I am overwriting it based on what I get out of EmployeeCommon.GetOrder(trading, orderSuccessful);
After that I assign to 
I then iterate again and do this originalOrder.OrderBean = order;
When I iterate again and get the new EmployeeCommon.GetOrder and add to list the existing one gets overwritten.

Comment: As an aside, this method could be simplified a lot; you're using too many variables and passing too much information as arguments, which makes it difficult to reason about.

Comment: originalOrder is passed as a parameter so there is only one instance of it

Comment: @donkeykong, yes that makes sense. Hence getting overwritten, even though I am assigning it to a newly instantiated processedOrdersHold? And adding this new object to the list?

Comment: As long as `originalOrder` remains unchanged, then every time you assign a value to a _member_ of that object, the original object will be changed. See marked duplicate for some details on what a "reference type" (i.e. `class`) is and what the implications of that are. Assigning that value to a different variable does nothing whatsoever to change the relationship between the original variable and the object to which it refers. That assignment doesn't create a new object, to be added to the list; it just puts the reference to the object into another variable.

Comment: Thanks @PeterDuniho, that makes sense.